# Class App\Http\Middleware\CORS does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, cors

There are lots of result but nothing worked for me. It works in local development but doesn't work in a live server and give `Class App\Http\Middleware\CORS does not exist` error..

I am following these instructions and using this class.. Please see it.. 
https://gist.github.com/technoknol/1a35ca4b150215f491d5c807940bd4ef

Comment: Change your includes to requires. This way when one fails you will know what the error is

Comment: Did you run composer on the server, and is the library under require in composer.json?

Comment: HI, the problem is solved now. It seems file naming problem

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, I think this may help others. I had the file with name `Cors.php` and class name `CORS` and this was the problem. I have changed this file name  to `CORS.php` and it worked fine. It seems a live server is case sensitive while the local development case insensitive.